# Is there a way to get dependency tree from webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4, webpack-plugin, webpack-loader

I have a big project with different types of dependencies in it: js, scss, svg, png, etc...
My webpack is configured and bundles my code, I am happy with it.

But I want to get some kind of hash of all my dependencies (including binaries and all files formats). And what is most important: I do not want to build my code during this. For this purpose I need, for example, array of all files inside all of entry points or at least some kind of dependencies tree.

I tried to use compilation hook `finishModules`, but it completes after the compilation. Also tried some other hooks of compiler, don't remember which exactly.

I tried to write loader, but it seems like by default there is only source code of high-level files (like entry points themselves).

I'd be happy to receive some direction to move with my problem.

Comment: Why not utilize webpack stats?
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/stats/

Comment: Because it can be received only after build, and I don't want to build. I want to get information if something changed to make decision, run build or not.

Comment: do you need to know when some file is changed as [`fs.watch()`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener) does?

Comment: No, I need to improve my deploy process like this: get some checksum of files, check if it changed (according to some saved checksum and bundles), and either run build or just get previously built bundles.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seems like I can solve my problem using https://github.com/pahen/madge